# Form unload not fired when i am used debugging

Tags: vb6

I used vb6.6 application and my form unload method not fired when I click ok button. It came from One of my .ocx file control but other cancel button fired because that's not an ocx control button

Answer (score 0):

when in debug mode, events don't fire in the order they normally do.   My suggestion is that you use the Debug.Print to send tracking msgs to the immediate window rather than trying to 'step debug' thru that event.   Put a break in your code just before your first ( of potentially many ) Debug.Print statements ... then when the debugger stops there, switch out of debug mode and let the code run free, using the messages in the immediate window to tell you what you would have gathered visually while stepping thru the code.    Have done this many times, successfully.  It takes some patience to get it to work, but once mastered, it works every time.